# psql won't login, while pgAdmin logs me in successfully? Wrong command?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I have a remote machine and I am trying to log-in into a postgres database with the following command (run as Linux `root` user via `ssh`, i.e. locally on that machine):

```
# psql -d mydatabase -U postgres -W
Password for user postgres: <here goes my password>
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

For some reason this fails (tried ~5 times).

But when I login to the same database using pgAdmin (i.e. remotely) with same role (postgres) and same password, it logs in successfully every time.

What's wrong with `psql` command I use? If it is correct, can you suggest any troubleshooting steps?

EDIT: So the problem is that in `pg_hba.conf` remote and local connections are treated differently. Remote ones are configured properly. The question is why locals don't work.

For locals, I have in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Do I understand correctly that for `localhost` connections it first tries peer authentication, and if it fails it doesn't attempt `md5` and just returns error?

Comment: PgAdmin will be using tcp/ip to localhost (127.0.0.1), `psql` will be using unix sockets. Check `pg_hba.conf` and the client authentication chapter of the manual.

Comment: You can force psql to use an inet socket by specifying a hostname: `psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 mydb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

psql in default is trying to login via peer. This means, you have to be logged in as postgres on your local machine. You can force psql to use TCP/IP, you need tpo specify a host, which can be localhost, so the call could look like:

```
psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1
```

Another way would be to adjust your settings. I see two ways to change your current local settings:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

1) Allow all users to login without password from localhost by setting line

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

This is very dangerous and shouldn't be done IMHO.

2) Another way could be to create a database user with same user name as your system login and grant all rights to this account

And of course, which is what I usually do in such cases: Run psql in context of postgres user e.g. by sudo -u postgres psql or with su -u postgres -c "psql ..."